# Paint text in a Canvas in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to paint text inside a Canvas (auto adding the new lines when needed). Thats my sample code:

```
    Bitmap src= getBitmap();
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
    cs.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, null);
    TextPaint tp= new TextPaint();
    tp.setTextSize(.....);
    tp. //Custom the text properties
    StaticLayout sl= new StaticLayout(text, tp, src.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
    sl.draw(cs);
```

this works fine for painting the text with **"center|top"** gravity. But I'd need to be able to make "center|center" and "center|bottom". 
Given the canvas **src** and **sl** is easy to calculate where sl must go but
how can I change the "start point" for the StaticLayout in order to add it a padding?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the StaticLayout/DynamicLayout some more space in the "width" arguement,
to get some padding on top/bottom of your text you can use "canvas.translate(x,y)"

Comment: What about on the right, how do I add padding so text don't get cut off?